# Sending Image From Android to C# webservice

Tags: c#, android, web-services, encoding, android-image

I'm sending image from Android to C# webservice. I always get a black image.Can anyone help?

Android side:

```
 public void save(View v) {           
        mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);           
        ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,40, outputStream);
        byte[] imgByte = outputStream.toByteArray();
        String base64Str = Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, Base64.DEFAULT);
       // Send base64Str to server
}
```

C# side:

```
[WebMethod]
public void GetImage(string base64ImageStr)
{           
      byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64ImageStr);
      //Save imageBytes to DB                
 }
```

I'm calling it from DB:

```
 public ActionResult Image(){
        var bytes=GetBytesArrayFromDB(id);
        return File(bytes, "image/jpeg");
    }
```

in View:

```
<img src='@Url.Action("Image")' alt="" />
```

Comment: Hi @zaza. I also be interested in this problem. But, I'm having trouble with sending the base64 string to webservice. Because, base64 encoded string length about ~103.000 chars. So, HTTP standarts aren't allow this length (`max length of URL  is 2000`). Can you share parts of code like:   `// Send base64Str to server`  and  `//Save imageBytes to DB` . Thanks.

Comment: Hi @MirjalalTalishinski. I'm using soap web services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure it out
I didn't Canvas it before sending it to server.
use this too

**Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
v.draw(canvas);**

```
 public void save(View v) {           
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getWidth(), v.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);           
            ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            mBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,40, outputStream);
            byte[] imgByte = outputStream.toByteArray();
            String base64Str = Base64.encodeToString(imgByte, Base64.DEFAULT);

            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            v.draw(canvas);

           // Send base64Str to server
    }
```

//send base64Str to server

```
import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
public class CallSoap
{
    public final String SOAP_ACTION = //url;
    public  final String OPERATION_NAME = "name of action";
    public  final String WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE = "asmx url";
    public  final String SOAP_ADDRESS = "soap address";
public CallSoap()
{
}
public String Call(String base64Str)
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSDL_TARGET_NAMESPACE,OPERATION_NAME);

    PropertyInfo pi=new PropertyInfo();
    pi.setName("base64Str");
    pi.setValue(base64Str);
    pi.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(pi);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.dotNet = true;
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE httpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(SOAP_ADDRESS);
    Object response=null;
    try
    {
        httpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        response = envelope.getResponse();
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        response=exception.toString();
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

}